# How to use just one socket to connect to the MongoDB with pymongo 3？

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I want to use one socket to connect to MongoDB in Multithreading.

```
#-*- encoding:UTF-8 -*-

import datetime
import threading
import time

import pymongo

conn = pymongo.Connection('mongodb://127.0.0.1', auto_start_request=False)

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print conn['fvck'].damnit.count(), datetime.datetime.now(), self.getName()
        time.sleep(10)

with conn.start_request():
    for i in range(100):
        MyThread().start()
```

The code just have one socket and PyMongo's version is 2.2rc.

[Citing the documentation for PyMongo 3](https://api.mongodb.org/python/3.0/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient):

> The `connect` option is added.
>
> The `start_request`, `in_request`, and `end_request` methods are removed, as
>   well as the `auto_start_request` option.
>
> The `copy_database` method is removed, see the [copy_database examples](https://api.mongodb.org/python/3.0/examples/copydb.html)
>   for alternatives.
>
> The `MongoClient.disconnect()` method is removed; it was a synonym for
>   `close()`.

```
client  = pymongo.MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017, connect=False)
```

The boolean `connect` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

> I want use one socket to connect to MongoDB in Multithreading.

In PyMongo 3, pass maxPoolSize=1. All application threads will share one socket.

> The boolean connect is not work.

That option determines when PyMongo makes its initial connections to the server. If set to True (the default) it attempts to connect immediately. If False, it attempts to connect when your application tries an operation. Note that in PyMongo 3 connection is done on a background thread.